# validation message is not showing in client side in mvc razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on MVC Razor and I want to validate my model as per condition.
codtion is if  IsDefaultMailingAddress is true then only DeliveryLine and Zip will be Required otherwise page is submitted.
I have searched so many artical  and got below metion blog
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2011/02/04/conditional-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-3.aspx

and I have implemented **Reqiuedif** in my model which is mentioned below

**my model:**
RequiredIf("IsDefaultMailingAddress",true, ErrorMessage = "Must add DeliveryLine ")]
public string DeliveryLine { get; set; }

RequiredIf("IsDefaultMailingAddress",true, ErrorMessage = "Must add Zip")]
public string Zip { get; set; }

public bool IsDefaultMailingAddress { get; set; }

Everything is working fine but the Problem is when i click submit buttion it is going to server side and there model state isvalid
showing false.why before going to server it is not showing all error message
"Must add DeliveryLine and Must add Zip"

please let me know what what should be implement this client side validation.

Answer (score 0):

You should have to enable ClinetValidation to get work around this. In the view just add the below html helper.

```
@Html.EnableClientValidation()
```

Comment: thanks for reply.are you sure  if i add @Html.EnableClientValidation() in my view.it will work and display all requiredif error message

Comment: Yes it will enable client event validation and you will see you validation before submit.

Comment: required error message is showing without adding @html.EnableClientValidation().but Problem is for RequiredIf error message.where i am doing silly mistake

Comment: No you said that "it is going to server side and there model state isvalid showing false.why before going to server it is not showing all error message", so this is the method to prevent go server side and show validation firstly.